# How to set emacs to recognize backtick and tilde with a Colemak keyboard layout?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, microsoft-windows

I've just installed emacs 24 on my Windows 7 32-bit OS. Usually, I activate Colemak keyboard layout and use it to do all sorts of typing (in browsers, spreadsheets or word processors). It works fine and has tilde (~) and backtick (`) on a key in the top left corner of the keyboard, between the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key and the <kbd>Tab</kbd>, at the left of key <kbd>1</kbd>.

[image]

In emacs, most of the Colemak keys are recognized but that key doesn't work. If I press it, emacs' cursor stops blinking and after 4-5 seconds types 'sssssssssss' or whatever alphabet key I pressed after that key. For now I've managed to get tilde to work by putting `(set global-key [f2] "~")` and was thinking of associating <kbd>F3</kbd> with backtick, but I was wandering if there's a way to make emacs recognize that key. That way I would get backtick by pressing the ordinary key and tilde by pressing it in combination with <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

### EDIT

I have downloaded the Colemak layout from the official Colemak Forum that caters to all users, whether on Windows, Linux or Mac. A zip file can be downloaded from section **[[5.1 DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL]](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14504410/Keyboards/dreymar/pkl/PortableKeyboardLayout_DreymaR.zip)** of a thread titled "[DreymaR's Big Bag of Keyboard Tricks - PKL/Windows Edition!](http://forum.colemak.com/viewtopic.php?id=1467)". The decompressed zip file has some folders and files inside, among them a *pkl.exe*. I have placed a shortcut to this file, next to Windows' "Start" button and everytime I log into my OS I double click it and launch Colemak. The 2 most important files contained in the zip file are *pkl.ini* and *layout.ini*, the latter being inside **layouts** > **colemak-eD_ISO** folder.

*pkl.ini* allows one to set the locale or language of the keyboard by adding this line `layout = colemak-eD-Lat_ISO:Colemak[eD]-ISO-It` and commenting out any other similar lines so they don't interfere. The *layout.ini* allows you to customize certain keys. I, for instance, tweaked it to allow CapsLock to write capital letters just like it does in QWERTY.

Below are 2 "Display help images" that come with the colemak bundle. The first is Ordinary keyboard, the second one shows changes as <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed. They resemble very much my keyboard layout. As it turns out, it's the top left corner key that doesn't get recognized by Emacs.

[image: colemak italian keyboard]
[image: keyboard changes with Shift key pressed]

### EDIT 2

The main reason why I need backtick to be recognized is so that I can use keyboard shortcuts in AUCTeX to get Greek alphabet. By default, to get the Greek letter alpha you can press backtick and <kbd>a</kbd>. This spurs EMACS to immediately substitute 'a' with 'α'. That's the use behind my question. I tried to work-around this problem by adding this line in my *.emacs* file: `(setq LaTeX-math-abbrev-prefix  "'")` but writing words such as *didn't* or *ain't* became problematic since EMACS kept substituting the single quote followed by letter 't' with Greek letter 'tau'.

Comment: Looks like that key does not, in fact, appear as a backtick key. Press `C-h c` and then the backtick key, what does Emacs tell you?

Comment: In "scratch" mode I typed `C-h c` and emacs responded `M-6-`. What does it mean? Can I set it to backtick and tilde? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Is the Colemak layout one that's bundled with Windows? Is your keyboard a Mac laptop as depicted in your question? I wonder why it would make the key something other than a backtick. Can you try an external keyboard and see if you have the same problem? What does the key do in another layout such as US QWERTY?

Comment: I use a Colemak script that I downloaded and customized as told by the author, from the Colemak forum [here](http://forum.colemak.com/viewtopic.php?id=1467) (see section 5.1). I have the Italian Colemak edition "keep local symbols" [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14504410/Keyboards/dreymar/doc/locale/Cmk-eD-it-ksym_Xm.png). The picture is a little old, the backtick has been moved to the left of key **1**.  The picture in my OP above is just for illustration's purpose. My laptop's keyboard looks different. When I'm in italian QWERTY that key does \ (backslash) and vertical line, |.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information. It's going to take some Windows expertise to figure this out.

Comment: I tried adding `(setq LaTeX-math-abbrev-prefix  "'")` in my _.emacs_ file. It sure works when I need to type Greek alphabet but it gets in the way of writing simple words such as  _didn't_ , _couldn't_ or _ain't_ because EMACS keeps inserting tau!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, but I don't know *how*, your Emacs is receiving the wrong keys, <kbd>M-6 M-9</kbd> instead of <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>M-2</kbd> instead of <kbd>~</kbd>.  The easiest solution would be to [translate](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html) those keys to the correct ones, but all <kbd>M-number</kbd> (being <kbd>number</kbd> a single digit numeric key) keys are bound to [`command digit-argument`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html), which is a really useful feature that would be a pity to lose.  This is why you get a long sequence of letters when you press a letter key after the backtick, they are 69, count them ;-)

Fortunately, also all <kbd>C-number</kbd> keys are bound to [`command digit-argument`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html) and, speaking for myself, I prefer to use <kbd>C-number</kbd> over <kbd>M-number</kbd>, so it won't hurt to translate <kbd>M-2</kbd>, <kbd>M-6</kbd>, and <kbd>M-9</kbd> to what you need.

To restore the wanted behavior add the following code to your init file:

```lisp
;; For the backtick
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "M-6") "")        ; Do nothing
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "M-9") (kbd "`")) ; Actually insert the backtick
;; For the tilde
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "M-2") (kbd "~"))
```

Comment: Probably it would be better to bind `M-6` to `ignore`, but it doesn't appear to be effective.