# How to fix 'Wrong type argument: characterp, 134217782'?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm using Org 8.2 on emacs 24.4, in a Windows 7 machine. Recently I've managed to install **cdlatex.el** script by saving this file in one of my 'load-paths'. As you may know, cdlatex is a minor mode that can work with Org-mode and helps speed up writing math in Org by the use of keyboard shortcuts. However, when in cdlatex I get this error message:

> Wrong type argument: characterp, 134217782

This error appears in the mini-buffer every time I press the backquote or backtick key on my keyboard (this symbol: <kbd>`</kbd>).

Clearly I must add some line in the *.emacs* configuration file to fix this problem otherwise I'm unable to use 90% of CDLaTeX commands from keyboard. Can someone please help me out? I'm not proficient in elisp (I just copy/paste other folks lines). This is what I've got in my .emacs file regarding tilde and backquote (they respond to the same key, on my laptop's keyboard, see [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/16749/620) for context):

```lisp
;;; a key for tilde symbol
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "M-2") (kbd "~"))
;;; a key for backtick symbol
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "M-6") "")
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "M-9") (kbd "`"))
```

## Edit 1

The reply to `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` is:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument characterp 134217782)
  format("No such math symbol %c on level %d" 134217782 1)
  apply(format ("No such math symbol %c on level %d" 134217782 1))
  error("No such math symbol %c on level %d" 134217782 1)
  (if (or (not symbol) (not (stringp symbol)) (equal symbol "")) (error "No such math symbol %c on level %d" char level))
  (let* ((cell (cdlatex-read-char-with-help cdlatex-math-symbol-alist-comb 1 cdlatex-math-symbol-no-of-levels "Math symbol level %d of %d: " "AVAILABLE MATH SYMBOLS.  [%c]=next level " cdlatex-math-symbol-prefix (get (quote cdlatex-math-symbol-alist-comb) (quote cdlatex-bindings)))) (char (car cell)) (level (cdr cell)) (entry (assoc char cdlatex-math-symbol-alist-comb)) (symbol (nth level entry))) (if (or (not symbol) (not (stringp symbol)) (equal symbol "")) (error "No such math symbol %c on level %d" char level)) (if (or (not (texmathp)) (cdlatex-number-of-backslashes-is-odd)) (cdlatex-dollar)) (insert symbol) (if (string-match "\\?" symbol) (progn (cdlatex-position-cursor))))
  cdlatex-math-symbol()
  call-interactively(cdlatex-math-symbol nil nil)
  command-execute(cdlatex-math-symbol)
```

Comment: If you press `C-h k` and then `\``, what command does it say this key is bound to?

Comment: This is what I get:  ` (translated from <M-kp-9>) runs the command cdlatex-math-symbol, which is an interactive Lisp function in ``cdlatex.el'.

It is bound to ` , <menu-bar> <Org> <LaTeX> <Insert math symbol>.

(cdlatex-math-symbol)

Read a char from keyboard and insert corresponding math char.
The combinations are defined in `cdlatex-math-symbol-alist'.  If not in a LaTeX
math environment, you also get a pair of dollars.

Comment: I'd like to point out here that `C-c {` is working in `org-cdlatex-mode`, it regularly inserts a math environment such as `align`. However when I try to enter some other code such as `- TAB` then it doesn't insert `\item` inside an `itemize` environment. I also notice that if I go via menu "Org", with the mouse, then the backquote works and I'm able to insert those math symbols including Greek letters. Maybe I should change the **cdlatex-math-symbol-alist**?

Comment: maybe try to use `\`` on its own without binding `M-9` to insert it, or have a different key to insert it (without the `M` modifier), just to see if this works.

Comment: Mmm... that's a little complicated for a newbie like me. I'm afraid (A) I don't know how to do that, (B) doing so will jeopardize things in other situations like in auctex

Comment: `M-x toggle-enable-debug-on-error RET`

Comment: that didn't work, I couldn't even complete the command, half-way through, it said `[No match]`.

Comment: @politza, `M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET` instead gave me some more feedback! See 'Edit 1' in my question.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you have loaded byte-compiled code from an older Emacs version.

First, check by loading the Lisp source file that defines the functions in question: `*.el`, not the byte-compiled file (`*.elc`). (It sounds like the file in question might be `cdlatex.el` - but it might be another file.)

If that solves the problem (and it should), then you can byte-compile the library again, using your more recent Emacs version (the same version you are using at runtime). `M-x byte-compile-file`.

Comment: How do I load the Lisp source file? Any keyboard magic I don't know about? Isn't it done automatically as I launch Emacs? I downloaded the script from [Carsten Dominik's gitHub repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cdominik/cdlatex/master/cdlatex.el), and made sure it ended with ***.el**, not *.elc. I placed the file with other *.el scripts, in _<C:\Program Files\emacs-24.4\share\emacs\24.4\lisp\>_    which is _one_ of my load paths, as I discovered by typing `C-h v RET load-path RET`. Should I byte-compile 'the library' (what?), do I open an org file and then type `M-x byte-compile-file`?

Comment: If you have no *.elc files then the *.el files will be loaded. You can move any *.elc files out of the way (out of your `load-path`. You can also load any file manually, using `M-x load-file`. E.g., you can load the *.el file using `load-file`, even if the *.elc has already been loaded - the *.el code will replace the *.elc code that was loaded earlier.

Comment: Nope, the problem is still there. I'm using version 4.7 (2014) of cdlatex.el

Comment: Trying to guess the problem from this altitude is not efficient, for me at least. Unless someone else here has a better insight or you provide a lot more info, my suggestion is to contact the maintainer of `cdlatex.el`. (There might even be a bug here.) In my experience, I have seen that error message when I've loaded a version of the library that was compiled with an older version of Emacs, and loading the source file (or a byte-compiled file from the same or similar Emacs version) solved it. That's all.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, basically there's a conflict of versions between Emacs and _cdlatex.el_? I may have downloaded a version of _cdlatex.el_ that maybe is not meant for Emacs 24.4?

Comment: I don't suspect that. But you can check cdlatex.el - it *should* tell you what Emacs versions it supports. (If it does not, ask the maintainer to put that information somewhere, such as in the file header.) I suspected byte-compilation with an older Emacs version. But if you get the same behavior using only source files (*.el; no *.elc files), then my guess must have been wrong.

Comment: I don't mean to drag this too long, but just to clear things up, when you wrote in your answer "First, **check** by loading...", does that imply some special command? (Sorry for the dumb question, I'm no elisp expert). Can you please help me customize the cdlatex-math-symbol-prefix variable to use another symbol instead of backquote, say '•' (a bullet mark)? `(setq cdlatex-math-symbol-prefis ...)` something? Maybe this can be a work around.

Comment: `M-x load-file RET cdlatex.el RET`. You do that from the directory where that file resides (use `M-x cd` to get there). Or you specify the complete (i.e., absolute) file name (i.e., including the directory) to `load-file`.

Comment: To customize `cdlatex-math-symbol-prefix`, use `M-x customize-option RET cdlatex-math-symbol-prefix RET` (this assumes that it is in fact a user option). I cannot help with what values you should set it to - I know nothing about that option or about library `cdlatex.el`.

Answer (score 2):

I found a work-around by remapping backquote (or back-tick). In my *.emacs* file I wrote:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "C-1") (kbd "`"))

;;; how to tell cdlatex that it should keep Org-mode's backquote symbol?
;(eval-after-load "cdlatex"
;  '(define-key minor-mode-map (kbd "M-9") nil) ; clean it up
;  '(define-key minor-mode-map (kbd "M-9") (kbd "`"))) ; now set it
```

I tried the second part, the one that's commented out but it gave me trouble so I left it out. This remapping allows me to enter the math symbols menu by invoking backquote. Once inside I can cycle through the 3 levels of symbols by pressing `@`. Sure enough I changed the backquote character necessary to cycle and put instead 'at the rate of' with the commands *@Drew* suggested above: `M-x customize-option RET cdlatex-math-symbol-prefix RET`.

In case I need to escape backquote I can type **C-q `**.