# How to bind a terminal command to a key for python code autoformatting using autopep8

Tags: key-bindings, python, terminal-emacs, shell-command, formatting

I'd like to autoformat my python code from the buffer that contains it with a key.

I was looking at [this tutorial](https://avilpage.com/2015/05/automatically-pep8-your-python-code.html). One can autoformat the code from the terminal with the command:

```
autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive <filename>
```

I tested it and it works. I'd like to have that bound to a key. The tutorial provides the code:

```
(defcustom python-autopep8-path (executable-find "autopep8")
  "autopep8 executable path."
  :group 'python
  :type 'string)

(defun python-autopep8 ()
  "Automatically formats Python code to conform to the PEP 8 style guide.
$ autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive <filename>"
  (interactive)
  (when (eq major-mode 'python-mode)
    (shell-command 
     (format "%s --in-place --aggressive %s" python-autopep8-path
             (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name))))
    (revert-buffer t t t)))

(bind-key "C-c C-a" 'python-auto-format)

(eval-after-load 'python
  '(if python-autopep8-path
       (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'python-autopep8)))
```

that added to my `.emacs` file, but when I try `Ctrl C - Ctrl A` I get the error: `Wrong type argument: commandp, python-auto-format`.

Reading the first answer of [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19761/how-to-fix-wrong-type-argument-characterp-134217782) question, they suggest the problem in their case might be that the snippet is for an older version of emacs. I suspect the problem here is the same as the tutorial is from 2015. I have no idea how to modify that code, so that it binds `Ctrl C - Ctrl A` to the code autoformatting.

Comment: The error indicates that the there is no command named `python-auto-format`. You named the command `python-autopep8`, so try that instead.

Comment: Yes, that solved it. Thanks.

Comment: One of you should add that as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Dan in the comments, the problem was that the piece of code invoked `python-auto-format`, which undefined. Instead, it should be `python-autopep8`.  The functioning code looks like this:

```
(defcustom python-autopep8-path (executable-find "autopep8")
  "autopep8 executable path."
  :group 'python
  :type 'string)

(defun python-autopep8 ()
  "Automatically formats Python code to conform to the PEP 8 style guide.
$ autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive <filename>"
  (interactive)
  (when (eq major-mode 'python-mode)
    (shell-command 
     (format "%s --in-place --aggressive %s" python-autopep8-path
             (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name))))
    (revert-buffer t t t)))

(bind-key "C-c C-a" 'python-autopep8)  ;;this is the part I changed to make it work

(eval-after-load 'python
  '(if python-autopep8-path
       (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'python-autopep8)))
```